# Not able to parse a string that contains utf8 0xc2 0x85 characters using jdom parser

Tags: jdom

I have a utf-8 string that contains 0xc2 0x85 characters. Eclipse treats this as whitespace. Certain application treats this as '...'.

Since, the string is xml, I'm using jdom parser and the jdom parser fails and gives the following exception.

org.jdom.input.JDOMParseException: Error on line 1: Content is not allowed in prolog.
    at org.jdom.input.SAXBuilder.build(SAXBuilder.java:381)
    at org.jdom.input.SAXBuilder.build(SAXBuilder.java:764)

Any idea on why the jdom parser doesn't treat this as whitespace? What else can i do to have the parser validate the xml successfully? All the other elements in the xml string seems fine.

Comment: 0xc2 0x85 is the utf-8 for unicode character U+0085 (Next line). http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/85/index.htm

Comment: U+85 is valid in XML and is a "next line" (NEL) control code, used as whitespace.  However, it is rarely used and is invalid in other formats, such as HTML.  It was included for compatibility with an old IBM format. 
 I would not recommend ever using it.  It is also easily confused with the CP-1252 character for an ellipsis, whose raw value is 0x85 but which should be represented in Unicode as U+2026.  Some software (such as browsers) may encounter it, assume it's improperly encoded CP-1252 and (wrongly) display an ellipsis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whitespace has a very specific meaning in XML. Outside the root Element in XML the only characters you are allowed are  [(#x20 | #x9 | #xD | #xA)+](http://www.w3.org/TR/2004/REC-xml11-20040204/#NT-S)   (space, carriage return, newline, and tab).

The prolog area in the XML is allowed to contain [limited structures](http://www.w3.org/TR/2004/REC-xml11-20040204/#NT-prolog), and space.

The characters you have shown are not allowed in valid XML outside the root element. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

JDOM (or the SAX parser, actually) does not have any problem parsing that character. The exception you get is invariably caused by illegal characters before the xml prolog:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

It might be that you have "invisible" characters before that, but they are there, still.

Comment: These characters are not present before the xml prolog. However, it's in between the xml prolog <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> and the root element. I'm not sure if these characters should be  part of the prolog or content. Looks like jdom treats these characters to be part of prolog. What is correct as per the xml spec?

Comment: The prolog is everything prior to the root element... http://www.w3.org/TR/2004/REC-xml11-20040204/#NT-document  This is **not** JDOM being 'difficult', but rather it is (together with any support libraries) ensuring that you have valid XML

Comment: Yes, I should have said "before or in the xml prolog".